# How to keep Docky above all windows? 

Tags: 11.04, docky

I want to prevent Docky from hiding but I also want it to dodge windows so Docky is above everything.

Is there a way to do this whether within or out of the application?

I am using 11.04 classic desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no option in the Settings to achieve this. 
**But I know a workaround:**

1.Right click on the Docky icon in the dock and go to Settings.
In Settings, choose **Windows Dodge** under Dock Configuration. Check **Fade on Hide** too.

[image]

2.Now Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> , and open `gconf-editor`.

Navigate to `/apps/docky-2/Docky/Interface/DockPreferences/Dock1/` and chnage the value of `FadeOpacity` to 1.

[image]

3.Restart Docky.

[image]

Comment: Anytime.. Glad to help.